# nor any of its super class is known to this context in jaxb

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

Im getting below exception when trying send a soap request through stubs.

```
    [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class com.domain.Test nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.domain.Test nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:408)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:206)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:129)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:210)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
```

The way im executing this is

```
NmsRtEvent event = new NmsRtEvent(); // WebServiceClient
RtEventMethodsSoap methodsSoap = event.getRtEventMethodsSoap(); //WebService
Element element = new Element();
element.setAny(new Test());
plId = methodsSoap.pushEvent(token,element);
```

Test class

```
@XmlType(namespace = "http://www.test.com/test")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Test implements Serializable{

    private int id;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) says about @XmlSeeAlso -

> Instructs JAXB to also bind other classes when binding this class.

You used annotation @XmlSeeAlso with Test.class values, its not correct. It should other class that need to be bind when you bind Test class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I removed the annotation from there. Test class is binding to Element class which is a generated one (stub class) .